# Pivoting SQL Server 2005 for unknown number of rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

My table is a dynamic one. E.g.:

```
id      SUBJECT
1   his
2   math
3   sci
4   opt
5   ENG
6   SOC
```

The number of rows is not limited. There could be a hundred. I want output like this:

```
ID 1     2     3      4     5      6  

   HIS  MATH    SCI   OPT   ENG   SOC
```

I could use a pivot query, but I would have to know the number of columns. How can I do this without knowing the number of columns in advance?

Comment: i did build a pivot-query with about 200 columns for some customers and then they couldn't see it on their monitors, so they exported it to excel and couldn't see it by entire on their monitors so they printed it out but even landscape on A3 and a 6 point font helped: guess...


...they couldn't see or read all the columns. So what for is this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got an answer but it's very tricky

1. create  a table for all your records
2. count the records
3. create a table with that much number of columns
4. create a comma separated variable for the table which has records
5. then split the comma separated variables into multiple columns

here is the code

```
DECLARE  @HEADDESC NVARCHAR(150)
DROP TABLE #HEADS
CREATE TABLE #HEADS
(
    ID INT IDENTITY
   ,HEADS NVARCHAR(150)
   ,NU INT 
)
DECLARE @NO INT;
SET @NO = 0
DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR (
    SELECT  HEADDESC 
    FROM GMC.FEEHEAD_MASTER 
    WHERE CODE = 'GF' AND HEADDESC <> '')
OPEN C1
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @HEADDESC

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS  = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @HEADDESC
    SET @NO = @NO+1 
    INSERT INTO #HEADS(HEADS,NU) 
    VALUES(@HEADDESC,@NO)

    FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO @HEADDESC
END
--SELECT * FROM #HEADS
CLOSE C1
DEALLOCATE C1
DECLARE @COLNO INT

SET @COLNO = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #HEADS)

DECLARE @COLUMNS VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @COLUMNS = COALESCE(@COLUMNS +','+  CAST(HEADS AS VARCHAR) ,
       CAST(HEADS AS VARCHAR))
FROM #HEADS
--GROUP BY HEADS

DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(100)

SET @value = ',1,STUDENTIDNO,STUDENTNAME,'

SET @COLUMNS = @VALUE+@COLUMNS
SET @COLNO = @COLNO+4
--SELECT @COLUMNS
DROP TABLE  #HEADSCOMMA
CREATE TABLE #HEADSCOMMA(HEADS NVARCHAR(3000))

INSERT INTO  #HEADSCOMMA VALUES (@COLUMNS)

DROP TABLE #TEMP
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(COL1 NVARCHAR(1000))
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @COL NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @COL1 INT
DECLARE @COLNAME NVARCHAR(1000)

SET  @COL1 = 2
SET @COL = 'COL'
PRINT @COL1
--SET @COLNAME = @COL +CAST(@COL1 AS NVARCHAR(10))

WHILE @COL1 < =@COLNO
BEGIN
    SET @COLNAME = @COL +CAST(@COL1 AS NVARCHAR(100))
    PRINT @COLNAME
    SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE #TEMP ADD '+@COLNAME+' NVARCHAR(100)'
    EXEC(@SQL)
    SET @COL1= @COL1+1
END


--SELECT * FROM #HEADSCOMMA -- COMMA SEPERATED VALUES
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(8000), @DATA VARCHAR(8000)
--DROP TABLE  #NORMALISEDTABLE
--CREATE TABLE #NORMALISEDTABLE (HEADS NVARCHAR(200))
SELECT @S=''

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #HEADSCOMMA WHERE HEADS>@S)
BEGIN
    SELECT @S=HEADS FROM #HEADSCOMMA WHERE HEADS>@S
    PRINT @S
    SELECT @DATA=''''+REPLACE(@S,',',''',''')+''''
    PRINT @DATA
    INSERT INTO #TEMP
    EXEC('SELECT '+@DATA)
END

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

will give the records

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL is an option.

Comment: but how to use if the columns are unknown?

Comment: Do you have atleast the range of values where id will fall into ?

Comment: quite tricky, how about doing a distinct on that table with your conditions and getting the values out to form the dynamic string.